# Negative Margin covering a link

Tags: html, css, position

So i have elements on a page some have a negative margin but when applying a negative margin it seems that the browser renders a blank box over what i need and covers other links on the page.

I set up a test here so you can see. All the buttons under the steps should be active.

http://jsfiddle.net/xXsB8/1/

```
.stepInfo_left {
float:left;
margin-left: -100%;
display:none;
}
.stepLabel_left {
float: right;
/* the thing that changed */
margin-right:20px; 
}
```

Also if somebody is able to help me align the links under the step on the left one under the label better that would be greatly appreciated too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step containers are what's causing the problem, here they are with a red outline: 
http://jsfiddle.net/5C3V5/

as you can see they are overlapping with the buttons. you can give them a `height:0;` to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `#step20` is placed [over the other "steps"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEVUb.png).

Your element positioning is completely off. What @Jan Drewniak suggests will fix the issue but you should consider rewrite the logic and positioning of your page from scratch or else you will face more problems in the (near) future.

Comment: yeah I agree, it's a pretty hairy mess.

Comment: So to give a better understanding of what i am trying to accomplish here is the whole piece. The steps are being built with JS so i'm very open to any suggestions as to what the best logic for this might be. link: http://denniscliment.com/AppMap/

Comment: well that certainly puts the question in perspective. Given it's a pretty unique layout and all the elements are positioned with js, the best logic is probably 'whatever works' :P